# How to match legend colors and plot colors in overlapping area plots in ggplot2

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
head(MP_rates_dateformat) 
       Month repo revrepo bankrate CRR Callrate  WPI GDP  FED
1 2001-04-01 9.00    6.75        7 8.0     7.49 5.41 4.6 4.50
2 2001-05-01 8.75    6.50        7 7.5     8.03 5.60 4.6 4.00
3 2001-06-01 8.50    6.50        7 7.5     7.24 5.30 4.6 3.75
4 2001-07-01 8.50    6.50        7 7.5     7.19 5.23 5.3 3.75
5 2001-08-01 8.50    6.50        7 7.5     6.94 5.41 5.3 3.50
6 2001-09-01 8.50    6.50        7 7.5     7.30 4.52 5.3 3.00
```

I am trying to plot timeseries overlapping area plots for variables `repo` and `revrepo` using `ggplot2`.

```
p2 <- ggplot(MP_rates_dateformat, aes(x= Month)) + geom_area(aes(y=repo, color="repo"), fill="yellowgreen") + geom_area(aes(y=revrepo,color="revrepo"), fill="dodgerblue", alpha=0.7, linetype="dotted") + labs(color="")+ labs(title="Overlapping - Repo & Reverse Repo") 

p2
```

[image]

As we can see the legend is showing with same colors fills in legend boxes for both variables. I want it to show the correct corresponding colors i.e. yellowgreen for `repo` and dodgerblue for `revrepo`.

Suppose I melt the data as:

```
df <- reshape2::melt(MP_rates_dateformat[, c("Month", "repo", "revrepo")], id="Month")

head(df, 3)

      Month variable value
1 2001-04-01     repo  9.00
2 2001-05-01     repo  8.75
3 2001-06-01     repo  8.50

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Month)) + geom_area(aes(y=value, fill=variable)) + labs(title="Non-Overlapping - Repo & Reverse Repo")
```

[image: plot2]

But this is giving me non-overlapping area plots with correct legend....BUT I am looking for overlapping area plot.

Comment: Melt (gather) your data so that values for repo and revrepo will be collected under one variable. Map this variable to fill et voila.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on the idea of melting/gathering the data, using `fill` in `ggplot` combined with `position = "identity"`. Note that the order of the columns is important as the smallest value `revrepo` should be plot after the first one `repo`.

```
library("tidyr")
df_gather <- gather(select(MP_rates_dateformat, 1:3), variable, value, -Month)

library("ggplot2") 
ggplot(data = df_gather, aes(x = Month)) +
  geom_area(aes(y = value, fill = variable), position = "identity")
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got it!

```
library("tidyr")

long_DF<- MP_rates_dateformat[,1:3] %>% gather(variable, value, -Month)
head(long_DF)

    Month variable value
1 2001-04-01     repo  9.00
2 2001-05-01     repo  8.75
3 2001-06-01     repo  8.50
4 2001-07-01     repo  8.50
5 2001-08-01     repo  8.50
6 2001-09-01     repo  8.50

library("ggplot2") 

ggplot(data = long_DF, aes(x = Month)) +
geom_area(aes(y = value, fill = variable), position = "identity") +   labs(fill="") + xlab('\nYears') + ylab('LAF Rates (%)\n') + labs(title="Overlapping - Repo & Reverse Repo\n")
```

[image]

Comment: thnx @Erwan for giving some idea to tackle the issue

Comment: Would be more happy if somebody can suggest me as to how to change the colors of the plot from the default to say colors like yellowgreen for `repo` and dodgerblue for `revrepo`