# How to change plot colors from default to custom colors in overlapping area plots in ggplot2

Tags: r

I have created the following overlapping area plots in ggplot2:

```
head(MP_rates_dateformat) 
         Month repo revrepo bankrate  CRR Callrate   WPI  GDP  FED width
1   2001-04-01 9.00    6.75     7.00 8.00     7.49  5.41  4.6 4.50   225
2   2001-05-01 8.75    6.50     7.00 7.50     8.03  5.60  4.6 4.00   225
3   2001-06-01 8.50    6.50     7.00 7.50     7.24  5.30  4.6 3.75   200
4   2001-07-01 8.50    6.50     7.00 7.50     7.19  5.23  5.3 3.75   200
5   2001-08-01 8.50    6.50     7.00 7.50     6.94  5.41  5.3 3.50   200

library("tidyr")

long_DF<- MP_rates_dateformat[,1:3] %>% gather(variable, value, -Month)
head(long_DF)

       Month variable value
1 2001-04-01     repo  9.00
2 2001-05-01     repo  8.75
3 2001-06-01     repo  8.50
4 2001-07-01     repo  8.50
5 2001-08-01     repo  8.50
6 2001-09-01     repo  8.50

library("ggplot2") 

ggplot(data = long_DF, aes(x = Month)) +
geom_area(aes(y = value, fill = variable), position = "identity") + 
labs(fill="") + xlab('\nYears') + ylab('LAF Rates (%)\n') +   labs(title="Overlapping - Repo & Reverse Repo\n")+ geom_line(data = MP_rates_dateformat, aes(x=Month, y=width/100, color = "width"),size=1.05)+ labs(color="")
```

[image]

As you can see the plot has default colors and the line plot also is in default color.I would like say colors like yellowgreen for `repo` and dodgerblue for `revrepo` and darkblue for`width`.Also these colors should reflect in the legend also. Bottom line is how to get custom colors in the above plots.

In an earlier stack overflow  qs--[How to match legend colors and plot colors in overlapping area plots in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650597/how-to-match-legend-colors-and-plot-colors-in-overlapping-area-plots-in-ggplot2/34658442#34658442...the) problem there was getting the legend colors to match the default overlapping area plots but here the issue is different....as how to get different user defined colors in the plot  rather than the default colors which ggplot2 gives.

Comment: In an earlier stack overflow qs--How to match legend colors and plot colors in overlapping area plots in ggplot2 problem there was getting the legend colors to match the default overlapping area plots but here the issue is different....as how to get different user defined colors in the plot rather than the default colors which ggplot2 gives.

Comment: check `scale_fill_manual` : http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_manual.html.

Comment: See comment on other question: `scale_fill_manual`.

Answer (score 2):

Got it ...

```
library("ggplot2") 
ggplot(data = long_DF, aes(x = Month)) +
geom_area(aes(y = value, fill = variable), position = "identity") +   scale_fill_manual(values=c("yellowgreen","dodgerblue")) + labs(fill="") +   xlab('\nYears') + ylab('LAF Rates (%)\n') + 
labs(title="Overlapping - Repo & Reverse Repo\n")+ geom_line(data =  MP_rates_dateformat, aes(x=Month, y=width/100, color = "Width"),size=1.05)+ scale_color_manual(values="darkblue")+ labs(color="")
```

[image]